# Создание папки в скрипте и назначение прав на запись

Tags: bash, chmod

Имеется скрипт, который запускается из под рута, но при этом создает некоторые папки и файлы в домашней директории пользователя. Из-за этого папки оказыватся недоступны для пользователя (точнее доступны только для чтения), хотя должен быть доступ к их редактированию.

Знаю, что можно использовать `chmod`, но прописывать его в каждом случае не очень радует (особенно если учесть количество создаваемых файлов и папок).

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно установить права при создании, то можно использовать:

```
mkdir -m 777 dirname
```

Созданная директория будет доступна на чтение и запись всем пользователям.

Comment: с копированием и перемещением также будет работать?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch у `cp` нету опций, но можно однострочником делать, отделяя точкой с запятой: `cp log.log /home/user/Documents ; chown user:user /home/user/Documents/log.log`.

Comment: а смысл делать однострочником?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch кому как нравится)

Comment: окей, вот только когда указывается user:user то как определить юзера? Ведь `$USER` - это будет как раз таки root

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а вам для конкретного юзера надо? Если для всех, то можно так: `cp log.log /home/user/Documents ; chmod 777  /home/user/Documents/log.log`

Comment: как на счет пройтись по всем пользователям  /etc/passwd  выделить тех у котооых ест домашняя папка и рекурсивно поправит права chown -R usr:usr

Comment: Липучка? Нет, не слышал.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, `echo "/home/user/down" | awk -F"/" '{print $3}'`